# Cargo does not match `rend = "^0.5"` against 0.5.0-pre2

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, semantic-versioning

I added the following line in my Cargo.toml:

```ini
rkyv = { git = "https://github.com/rkyv/rkyv", rev = "e2b0241a209e70e2fdd7ec43386ee72e2021d1a8" }
```

where `e2b024` depends on

```ini
rend = { version = "0.5", git = "https://github.com/rkyv/rend", branch = "master", default-features = false }
```

`rend/Cargo.toml` has

```
[package]
name = "rend"
version = "0.5.0-pre2"
```

However `cargo check` on my project complains there is incompatibility between specified versions.

```bash
Error: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/rkyv/rkyv`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/rkyv/rend`
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `rend = "^0.5"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.5.0-pre2
location searched: Git repository https://github.com/rkyv/rend?branch=master
required by package `rkyv v0.8.0 (https://github.com/rkyv/rkyv?rev=e2b0241a209e70e2fdd7ec43386ee72e2021d1a8#e2b0241a)`
```

The following site says the semver constraint '^0.5' matches '0.5.0-pre2'.

[https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/^0.5/0.5.0-pre2](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/%5E0.5/0.5.0-pre2)

Is there a workaround in my Cargo.toml to make this work without cloning and modifying `github.com/rkyv/*`?

Comment: I don't know about this site, but [Cargo will avoid pulling a prerelease version](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/resolver.html#pre-releases).

Comment: Probably, the only way is to patch `e2b024` to use the newer version or an older revision (and send a bug report).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chayim-friedman said, cargo will not match "0.5" against "0.5.0-pre2".